Microsoft Azure translators error "Translation failed. Please try again later
I am trying to user power automate to translate some text. I get an "InternalServerError" with a further explanation

'Translate_text' failed: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
(e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.PowerPlatform.ConnectorPlatform.CustomCodeConnector.CSharpScript.InProcess.Script+TranslationResult]'
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
(e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
.NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'statusCode', line 1, position
15.

The passed in text to the translator is already in an array format
[
  {
    "Text": "Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?"
  }
]

When I try to validate that the API resource in Azure is working - I am not able to get this to work either - I am testing out the "Try it dialog" (so I suspect that there is some sort of configuration  issue)

Appreciate any help anyone can offer in figuring this out :)
EDIT
Added an image from the Azure market place about the API


Can you share the API which you tested?

Hi Venkatesan - thanks for the reply. In power automate the connector is "Microsoft Translator V3". As to the API in Azure - I am not sure how to share the API. In terms of version info - the only thing I can see about the version/ details of the API are that is it the Microsoft Azure Service An AI service... - I have added a screenshot (sorry I cannot see where the version number are etc.)

Check the below answer


Microsoft Azure translators error "Translation failed. Please try again later.

I followed this MS-Document,
In the official document, they mentioned you need to create the translator with global region.
Even, when I tried with west Europe region, I got the same internal server error.
In my environment, I created translator with global region.
Portal:

Power Automate:

I followed the same steps in the document, and it translated the text from English to Spanish successfully in Power automate.

Hi Venkatesan - thanks for that. I have gotten the "Try me" in Azure to work correctly - I am still having some trouble within Power Automate (I think it may still be directing the call to the WesternEurope location - however, I think this may just be because I deleted the resource to correctly set the location to Global. I think this was the problem. As soon as I can verify I will come back and accept the answer. Thanks again for the help!

Amazing - it all works now. Thanks again for the help!

Glad to know it helped for you:)
